# Bonus Copy of Lightning Component in Winter 16/iOS 9

Tags: lightning-aura-components

One of my applications built on Lightning Components broke for iOS9 when the Winter 16 upgrade took place. I started getting intermittent null results when retrieving attributes associated with a component when processing an event, but only for the iOS installed application. After quite a bit of painful debugging (alerts! FTW) it looked like there was another copy of my main component which wasn't rendered. The fact that it wasn't rendered meant that it hadn't been through the setup code which was triggered from the afterScriptsLoaded event, so had null attributes.

I've managed to reduce this to a surprisingly simple example.  Here's the containing component - BookingTest:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

    <aura:handler event="c:Navigation" action="{!c.navigate}" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleInit}" />

    <c:BookingSub />    
</aura:component>
```

And its controller:

```
({
    navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.navigate(component, event);
    },
    handleInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('In init, component =' + JSON.stringify(component));
    }
)}
```

and helper:

```
({
    navigate : function(cmp, ev) {
        alert('Got navigate event for component ' + cmp.getGlobalId());
    }
})
```

the BookingSub component simply provides a mechanism to fire the event:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name="NavigationEvent" type="c:Navigation" /> 

    Sub component
    <button onclick="{!c.clicked}">Press to send event</button>
</aura:component>
```

its controller:

```
({
    clicked : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.clicked(component, event);
    }
})
```

and helper:

```
({
    clicked : function(cmp, ev) {
        $A.get("e.c:Navigation").
                    setParams({
                        "source": "source",
                        "target": "source"
        }).fire();
    }
})
```

and for the sake of completeness, the event:

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="BGMedia navigation event">
    <aura:attribute name="source" type="String" description="The source component"/>
    <aura:attribute name="target" type="String" description="The target (e.g. back/next)" />
</aura:event>
```

I then create a lightning component tab for the BookingTest component.

When I access this on Salesforce1 from my iPhone 6 running iOS 9.0.2, immediately after restarting the application, I get two alerts from the init method, for components with different global ids.

Alert 1 - note that the global Id is 1:99;a

[image]

Alert 2 - note that the global Id is 1:103;a - the tab only points to my BookingTest component, so I have no idea why two instances of this would be created.

[image]

If I then wait for the component to be rendered and click the 'Press to Send Event' to fire the Navigate event, I can see that both components receive it:

First component 1:99;a

[image]

and then component 1:103;a

[image]

The order in which these components receive the event can change, which is why I was seeing errors intermittently.

After I have been through this once after restarting the application, every time thereafter only a single component is instantiated.  I can't reproduce this on my iPad running iOS 8.4, or on any desktop client.